# Why my onInput doesn't work to change props.name?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React.js and I want to use onInput event to change the name, but it doesn't work.

Why is this happening? Do I write the wrong function(OnInputChange)?

Here is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import UserInput from "./Components/UserInput";
import UserOutput from "./Components/UserOutput";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    Username: [{ name: "Jacky" }]
  };

  OnInputChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      Username: [{ name: "event.target.value" }]
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UserInput OnInput={this.OnInputChange} />
        <UserOutput name={this.state.Username[0].name} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

my UserInput.js:

```
import React from "react";

const UserInput = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserInput;
```

my UserOutput.js:

```
import React from "react";

const UserOutput = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>I am {props.name}</p>
      <p>I am {props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserOutput;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:

1- You are not assigning `onChange` handler to input element in `UserInput` component, only passing that handler in props, automatically it will not work.

2- You are updating the value in state in wrong way, it should be `name: event.target.value` (not string).

Code:

```
const UserInput = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={props.OnInput}></input>
    </div>
  );
}



OnInputChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ 
    Username:[
      { name: event.target.value },
    ],
  });
}
```

Working Code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Username: [{ name: "Jacky" }]
  };

  OnInputChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      Username: [{ name: event.target.value }]
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UserInput OnInput={this.OnInputChange} />
        <UserOutput name={this.state.Username[0].name} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const UserInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={props.OnInput} />
    </div>
  );
};

const UserOutput = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>I am {props.name}</p>
      <p>I am {props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnInput` property is not passed down to your input component. It would have to be:

```
const UserInput = props => {
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={props.OnInput} />
      </div>
    );
};
```

Your handler uses a literal string `'event.target.value'`, it must read the value:

```
Username: [{ name: event.target.value }],
```

Also, there is no need to wrap username in an array and another object, you can just use:

```
Username: event.target.value,
```

and access `this.state.Username`.

and initialize as

```
state = {
  Username: "Jacky"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) You need to pass the event handler to your `UserInput` component.

```
const UserInput = ({ onChange }) => {...}
```

and then

```
<UserInput onChange={this.OnInputChange} />
```

2.) You need to use the passed event handler in your `input onChange`.

```
<input onChange={onChange} />
```

3.) You need to use `event.target.value` not `'event.target.value'`.

Comment: doesn't the class App not also need a constructor? how does it know what this.OnInputChange means if the function is never bound inside the constructor?

Comment: No, you don't need a constructor. If you use ES6 arrow function it auto-binds.